# Showing non Analytic Solutions to Heat Equation by example

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Hi I am supposed to show using the following example (which is given in the problem) the existence of non analytic solutions to the heat equation.

$ u_{t} -u_{xx}=0,\hspace{10pt}   u(0,x)=e^{-x^4}$

Where $-\infty<x<\infty$.

The problem I have is I don't really know what I should do. I am using Evans's book and using the theorems I can write the solution as

$u(t,x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}$ $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{(\frac{{-(x-y)^2})}{4t}-y^4}$ $dy $

But I don't know what to do after this. Is there a way to evaluate the integral or test analyticity without doing so? Any hints or help is appreciated greatly.

Edit: Corrected the wrong formula

Comment: I think you have an error in your formula. In the integral, you have to multiply the initial datum with the Gaussian kernel. You do not get $e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4t}}e^{{-y^4}/4t}$ but $e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4t}}e^{-y^4}$.

Comment: Thanks I corrected it,  I am still not sure how to evaluate the integral though